# Formatear alineación en campos o rango con Laravel-Excel

Tags: laravel-excel

pido su ayuda para poder realizar el formateo de las celdas o rango de mi exportación en excel, después de los encabezados, comienza el vaciado de la tabla a partir de la linea 9, columnas A a la O, necesito que el texto este con el formato de alineación: AJUSTAR TEXTO; ya que mis columnas tiene un ancho determinado por mi. exporto por Fromview, comparto mi funcion style, de antenamo gracias.

```
    public function styles(Worksheet $sheet){
    //hacer hoja horizontal
    $sheet->getPageSetup()->setOrientation(PageSetup::ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
    //formato de celda o rango en alineacion: ajustar texto

    return [
        // estilos para titulos
        2    => ['font' => ['bold' => true, 'italic' => true, 'size' => 16], 'alignment' => ['horizontal' => 'center']], 
        3    => ['font' => ['bold' => true, 'italic' => true, 'size' => 14], 'alignment' => ['horizontal' => 'center']], 
        // estilo para emcabezados de columnas
        8    => ['font' => ['bold' => true, 'italic' => true, 'size' => 14],
                'fill' => ['fillType' => 'solid', 'color' => array('rgb' => 'B5B8B1')],
                'alignment' => ['horizontal'=>'center']],
    ];
    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Para los que lleguen a necesitarlo, mi solucion fue entrar al archivo vendor\phpoffice\phpspreadsheet\src\PhpSpreadsheet\Style\Alignment.php y modificar de false a true la linea 57 referente a: protected $wrapText = true;

Comment: Yo no te recomiendo modificar el codigo fuente del paquete, ya que eso no se versionará, o cuando tengas que realizar una actualizacion, necesariamente tendrás que tocarlo nuevamente.

Answer (score 0):

Se puede establecer la opcion de alineación utilizando el metodo setWrapText();

```
    <?php
    namespace App\Exports;

    use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\WithStyles;
    use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Worksheet\Worksheet;

    class InvoicesExport implements WithStyles
    {
       public function styles(Worksheet $sheet)
       {
          $sheet->getStyle('A1')->getAlignment()->setWrapText(true);
       }
    }
```